# Bottle of Rum covered in leather

Tags: bottles, rum, identification

Had a bottle of Rum but can’t recall the name now; hoping members can identify it.

Bottle was shape and size of an ordinary narrow Bordeaux wine bottle (prob. 750ml). The glass bottle was covered with a leather casing, with (a thick?) stitching running up to the top. The bottle itself is not meant to be slipped out of the casing, it’s tight against the bottle (unless of course you were to cut the leather off).

Comment: We need to know more parameters to be able to even try to identify the bottle in question. What was it’s shape and size for example?

Comment: "*Bottle of Rum covered in leather*" How does one cover rum in leather and then get back into the bottle?  Perhaps the statement should read, Rum bottle covered in leather. This has been today's, Fun with words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the Ron Centenario Fundacion 20 anos

[image]

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. Knew I can count on you guys. (Our of curiosity, did you know the bottle or are you just an adept Googler?)

Comment: While I am an avid googler, I bought this bottle as a gift once, thats why I remembered it.